# Powering TTGO T-Call (ESP32 + SIM800L board) with only battery

Tags: batteries, power-electronics

I have recently bought a TTGO T-Call board. This nice board assembled together the ESP32 and SIM800L (GPRS module).
The board is working well if I am powering it up with it's USB type c input.
One of its' feature is to power up by lithium battery (3.7V) by the IP5306 power manager and pressing reset button for more than 1 second.
Of course the IP5306 also responsible to charge the battery in case there is another external DC source.

The IP5306 has a boost converter that close in case the button is pressed. The output of the IP5306 is regulated 5V which supply the whole board components.

When I connect battery (charged battery with Voc=4V) to the board and pressing the reset button I see that the 5v signal is rising fast to 4V and then dropping to ~2.2V. After that the signal is stable at ~2.2V and if I press again it jump to 4V and then drop down again...

The scheme can be found here:
https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800/blob/master/schematic/LilyGo-SIM800L-IP5306-20200811.pdf

Can anyone help to solve the problem to start up the board with battery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- The question on powering the TTGO-TCALL was answered through many experiences [in this issue: https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800/issues/29](https://github.com/Xinyuan-LilyGO/LilyGo-T-Call-SIM800/issues/29).
- [This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-qp-GwPrRk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-qp-GwPrRk) goes into more details about the behavior of the IP5306.
- This comment lists the I²C registers and what they do: https://github.com/m5stack/M5Stack/issues/135#issuecomment-476305363, since it's originally in Chinese and I can't find it in English (read the [data-sheet](https://github.com/m5stack/M5-Schematic/blob/master/Core/IIC_IP5306_REG_V1.4.pdf) along with it to know which bits are being referenced since some are reserved).

I don't really have an answer to your question, but I thought this might help.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue , I have used lipo battery. Turn out that to run this board you need better power delivery